# JavaScript getElementByName doesn't work

Tags: javascript

This simple JS can't set the value of "para". I guess getElementByName doesn't work. But why?

```
<script>
function fn()  
{   
    document.getElementById("para").setAttribute("name","hi");  
    document.getElementByName("hi").setAttribute("value","my value is high");  
}  
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onClick="fn()" value="click me">
<input id="para" type="text" />
```

Comment: See answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7

Comment: possible duplicate of [getElementsByName in IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's `getElementsByName` .  Note the plural.  It returns an array-like NodeList of elements with that `name` attribute.

Answer (score 19):

`getElementsByName` exists, which returns a collection of the elements. If you plan to find only one:

```
document.getElementsByName("hi")[0].setAttribute("value", "my value is high");
```

Edit: a, HTML there (didn't see that before the edit). No 'hi' element in HTML, possibly in some XML format there is...

Comment: You guys rock. getElementsByName("hi")[0] works just fine! Thank you.
Now i know only getElementById is not plural since id is unique.

Comment: 'hi' is not a tag name. it's just a name attribute for input'para' i set in the scirpt

Comment: Hehe, my fault, confused it with getElementsByTagName() :)

Answer (score 2):

not `getElementByName` but `getElementsByName`, and it returns array.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function fn() {
            document.getElementById("para").setAttribute("name","hi");
            x = document.getElementsByName("hi");
            x[0].setAttribute("value","my value is high");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="fn()">
    <input type="text" id="para" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, i find that document type must be declared to make getelementsbyname work.

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`