# How to get value of the  checked radio

Tags: javascript, radio-button, getelementsbyname

I am trying to get the value of the checked radio button with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    window.onload = initAll;

    function initAll(){     
        var allAnchors = document.getElementsByName("options");
        for ( var int = 0; int < allAnchors.length; int++) {
            if(allAnchors[int].className == "buttonLink"){
                allAnchors[int].onclick = fetchQuestion;
            }
        }
    }

    function fetchQuestion(){

        var toLoad = this.href;
        var selectedAnswer = "";                
        var allRadio = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for(var i = 0;i<allRadio.length; i++){
            if(allRadio[i].checked == true){
                selectedAnswer = allRadio[i].value;
            }
        }       
            alert(selectedAnswer);
                return false;
         }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="options" value="optA" />&nbsp; &nbsp;Operating System is used for Efficeint Resource Sharing Operating System is used for Efficeint Resource Sharing Operating System is used for Efficeint Resource Sharing <br/>
             <input type="radio" name="options" value="optB" />&nbsp; &nbsp;Operating System is used for Efficeint Resource Sharing <br/>
             <input type="radio" name="options" value="optC" />&nbsp; &nbsp;Operating System is used for Efficeint Resource Sharing <br/>
             <input type="radio" name="options" value="optD" />&nbsp; &nbsp;Operating System is used for Efficeint Resource Sharing <br/>
<a href="SubmitSheet" class="buttonLink">Submit</a>
        <a href="NextQuestion" class="buttonLink">Next</a>
        <a href="PreviousQuestion" class="buttonLink">Previous</a>
        <a href="PassQuestion" class="buttonLink">Pass</a>
</body>
</html>
```

here if i used `document.getElementByTagName("input")`, then it is working. but with `document.getElementByName("options")` it is not. So what's the problem with this?? Can't i use document.getElementByName with radio buttons.

Comment: Is `int` not a reserved keyword in js?

Comment: @geekchic: Nope, see [the spec](http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_7.htm#Section_7.6.1.1): `in`, `instanceof` and perhaps `interface` are, but `int` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you mean [document.getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName). Please notice the plural, since it can possibly return more than one node.

Comment: thanks alvaro, this was completely frustrating. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely that you are calling "document.getElementByName("options")"

getElementByName is undefined

you want to call getElementsByName,  which will return an element collection.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the method is plural `document.getElementsByName` because many items can share a name. If you want a single element, add an id and use `document.getElementById` or use name and narrow down your array.

[javascript getElementByName doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980830/javascript-getelementbyname-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
var allAnchors = document.getElementsByName("options");
```

To this instead:

```
var allAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

And your code [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/XqM6w/) as expected.

The `getElementsByName` has its own usage, but to grab all the anchor tags in the document you need other method which is `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 0):

See it yourself:

```
javascript:a=document.getElementsByName("options")[0];alert(a.value)

javascript:a=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];alert(a.value)
```