# HTML and javascript variables

Tags: javascript

How do you put a javascript variable into the `value=""` of an `<input>` box on a `<form>`

This must be easy but I do not know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the value of a input field with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-a-input-field-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not hard. Have a look at the example below:

HTML:

```
<input id="id_of_your_element">
```

Javascript:

```
var yourvariable = "Hello world!";
document.getElementById("id_of_your_element").value = yourvariable;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('element-id').value = 'The Value';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Value="<script type="text/javascript">document.write(yourVariableName);</script>"
```

Comment: You should avoid using document.write, especially for such a simple application where DOM methods are available - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

You can do just:

```
document.getElementById('inputId').value = yourVariable;
```

You can also use the jQuery library, it will:

```
$('#inputId').val(yourVariable);
```

- jQuery : http://jquery.com/
- function .val: http://api.jquery.com/val/