# Receiving the data from a form to a table which is already created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to receive the data from a form to another using the following code it worked.

```
var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0];
fname.value = getUrlVars()["fname"];
```

Now i want to receive the data from form to a table which is already created.
I used the code as
`$("table").html("<tr><td>"+fname +"</td><td>");` its not working.

Comment: What is `setinnerHTML`?

Comment: Inorder to set the value i used it.. plz say what is the correct syntax for setting a value which is obtained from another form..

Comment: If you want to set values of form you need to assign values to Input boxes. Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-a-input-field-with-javascript

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist
See [this to learn Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript) (Tools and advanced resources section)

Comment: In what way you know it "is not working"? have you tried using Firebug or jslint or any other code checking or debugging tool?

Comment: what is `getElementsByNamee`? Please make sure to post the actual code you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement,

```
var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname");
fname.innerHTML = "fname";
```

What is the element with name "**fname**"?

If its a form element like textbox then it should be like,

```
var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname");
fname.value = "fname";
```

your code will only work if the element is not a form element like **p** or **div**, etc tags.

**Edited Code:**

I hope your second page is student.html and you have written the receiveData() in this page. Then you need to read the url and set the parameter value to the element. Like the one am writing below, provided your wrote the same name in form 2 as in form1,

```
var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0];
fname.value = getUrlVars()["fname"];
```

2ndly yo can do this for textbox, but for the radio and dropdown you need to write som if-else statement.

Refer this http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

Hope you are getting what am willing to say.

**Re-Edited Code:**

Add this function with the receiveData() function.

```
function getUrlVars() {
 var vars = {};
 var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
  function(m,key,value) {
 vars[key] = value;
 });
 return vars;
}
```

Code for Radio Button,

```
var sex = document.getElementsByName("sex");
sexValue = getUrlVars()["sex"];
for(i=0;i<sex.length;i++)
{
 if(sex[i].value==sexValue)
 {
  sex[i].checked=true;
  break;
 }
}
```

Comment: I had made the changes which were said by u but not displaying the data in the form. please suggest more... element fname is the name given to the textfield First Name.

Comment: as per your question you are taking data from one form to another, so where are the two forms. can you put the html in your question or share a fiddle?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="skyblue">
<form action="student.html" name="StudentRegistration" onsubmit="return(validate());" method="post">     This is the first form...

Comment: again instead of using **document.getElementsByName("fname")** use **document.getElementById("fname")**. And dont forget to add id attribute in the **input** tag.

Comment: as getElementsByName('n') always return an array of elements who have their name as n. so, to access it use **getElementsByName('n')[0]** or any index you want. in your case it would be 0.

Comment: can you please show me the complete html of both the form, the source form and destination form.

Comment: <script src="validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="skyblue">
<form action="student.html" name="StudentRegistration" onsubmit="return(validate());" method="post">
<table cellpadding="2" width="30%" bgcolor="99FFFF" align="left"cellspacing="2">

<tr>
<td colspan=2>
<font size=4><b>Student Registration Form</b></font><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname"><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname" ><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Father Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="faname" ><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
still more..

Comment: <tr>
<td>Gender:</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female<br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Qualifiction:</td>
<td><select value="qualification" name="qualification">
<option value="-1" selected>select..</option>
<option value"Ph.D">Ph.D</option>
<option value="M.Tech">M.Tech</option>
<option value="B.Tech">B.Tech</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>

Comment: <td>Email-Id:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email"><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"><br></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Mobile No:</td>
<td><input id="number" name="mobileno" type="number" size="30""><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><textarea name="address"rows="10" colomns="15"></textarea><br></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>DOB:</td>
<td><select value="Day" Name="day"><select value="Month" name="month">
<option value="-1" selected>select..</option><select value="Year" name="year">
<option value="-1" selected>select..</option><td> this is first form

Comment: ok, whether the 2nd form is in the same page or other. Does 2nd form contains the same no of elements with same name?

Comment: I wrote what u said but the value is not getting by the second form

Comment: try using **var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[1]**

Comment: I used it the first name is displaying in the url but not in the form. what can i do??

Comment: first please clear, are those both forms are in the same page or in different page. if both are in same page then why are you using two forms? why you want to copy the data from one form to another.

Comment: Actually i created a registration form in one page with some fields. when i click the submit button then the details which were entered in that form must be displayed in the other form which is same as that form.

Comment: ok, then i hope 2nd form is in the 2nd page. so the code i had written in the edited code section in my answer will work. provided you have written the receiveData() function in the 2nd page.

Comment: i think i got your problem. try writing the receiveData() function in the 2nd page after the body end tag.

Comment: I wrote it after the </body> in second page but not got the data.

Comment: you have used method **post** in the first form. Use **get** to get data in url.

Comment: and remove the last statement i.e. submit statement. as you dont need to submit anything in the 2nd page.

Comment: I used get method and removed submit statement but still not got it.

Comment: are you using **var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0]**

Comment: I used var fname= document.getElementsByName("fname")[0]; but didnt got result.

Comment: check **Re-Edited Code** in my Answer.

Comment: I added as u said :                                          function ReceiveData()
{ 
var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0];
fname.value = getUrlVars()["fname"];                                                     function getUrlVars() {
 var vars = {};
 var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
  function(m,key,value) {
 vars[key] = value;
 });
 return vars;
}
}
</script> but didnt got.

Comment: no no, receivedata() and getUrlvars() are different functions. dont put the 2nd one inside the first one. put it different.

Comment: I wrote ur code in b/w <script>,</script> and my receive function next to it in <script></script> and  i wrote statement as                                       var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0];
fname.value = getUrlVars()["fname"];    didnt got it.'

Comment: script should be after the body end tag or just before it. the javascripts should be like this [http://jsfiddle.net/nitesh354/YhZVx/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/nitesh354/YhZVx/1/)

Comment: again the problem is who is calling the receivedata() function. so, don't write this function, rather simply write its contents.

Comment: where should i write the var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0];
fname.value = getUrlVars()["fname"];.. i wrote it before script. should i include it in {   }..

Comment: yes you should include it in the script tag like: **'<script> var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0]; fname.value = getUrlVars()["fname"]; //rest code      function getUrlVars(){  }</script>'**

Comment: Thanks a lot i got every fields data except radio button's data could you please tell about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot i got exact output...atlast by u i got the correct guidance thank u soo much..

Comment: you welcome, hope you will not mind to upvote this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with the code.

This is a useless statement, you need to save the result to some variable (not to mention `Nmae`):

```
document.getElementsByNmae("lname")
```

Should be:

```
var lname = document.getElementsByName("lname");
```

And then (`setinnerHTML` -> `innerHTML`):

```
lname.innerHTML="lname";
```

Comment: I wrote this in another form which will opens the another form by clicking on submit button.                                         <form action="student.html" name="StudentRegistration" onsubmit="return(validate());" method="post">

Comment: Then where is `Receivedata()` called?

Comment: plz say me where i have to call it.

Comment: I don't really know what exactly you want to do. With the code you've posted - I've said what the issues are.

Comment: i simply want to receive the data entered by user in registration form to the other registration form after clicking submit.

Comment: 1. If the other registration form is on the same page - try calling `Receivedata()` on form submit. 2. If it's on the other page - you need to use server side

Comment: It is in the same page and i called Receivedata() like this in the second form as shown:<form action="#" onsubmit="Receivedata()" name="Student" method="post">  still i cannot get it,.

Comment: Please read some docs on event handling. Form will still try to submit data and reload your page.

Comment: User could also use `.value` property of the `DOMElement` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) not your own imagination:

```
var newEl = document.getElementById("newElDay");
newEl.innerHTML = document.getElementById("oldElDay").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other problems which people have mentioned, perhaps you are missing this as the last line of your Javascript code inside Receivedata() :

```
document.getElementById('myform').submit();
```

Comment: document.getElementById('StudentRegistration').submit(); i wrote this but still not getting..  on the same form i wrote <form action="#" onsubmit="ReceiveData()" name="Student" method="post">..

Comment: Why is the action attribute "#" ? Are you are posting to the same page? In that case use "pagename.ext".