# Show a javascript variable on html textbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms

All I have to do is to show a number in a textbox and a button which add 10 every time I press it, here's my code (it doesn't work).

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var n=parseInt(ocument.forms["formNum"]["numero"].value);
    document.getElementById("numero").value=n;

    function sumar() {
        n=document.forms["formNum"]["numero"].value+10;
        document.forms["formNum"]["numero"].value=n;
    }

    function inicializar() {
        n=document.forms["formNum"]["numero"].value=0;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="formNum">
        <p>
            <input type="text" size="10" name="numero" id="numero" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="button" name="sumar" value="Sumar" onclick="sumar()" />
            <input type="button" name="inicializar" value="Iniciar a 0" onclick="inicializar()" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function sumar(){
           document.getElementById("numero").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("numero").value)+10;
       }

       function inicializar(){
           document.getElementById("numero").value=0;
       }
    </script>

    <form name="formNum">
        <p>
            <input type="text" size="10" name="numero" id="numero" value="0" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Sumar" onclick="sumar()" />
            <input type="button" value="Iniciar a 0" onclick="inicializar()" />
        </p>
     </form>
</body>
```

Five suggestions.

1. It is always better to give unique ids to your html elements.
2. Never name your HTML elements and javascript functions the same.
3. If you want to access the html element from javascript, if you know the id, use `getElementById`.
4. Use Firebug or Developer tools from the browser, to debug.
5. If you want to access your elements with the hierarchy, use `elements` in the form like this `document.forms["formNum"].elements["numero"].value`. Check this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.forms#Example_2.3AGetting_an_element_from_within_a_form)

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/DPJCR/

Comment: Could you please explain what you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Finally solved, it didn't work because i gave the samen "name" and "id" to the buttons...

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
<input type="text" id="mytext">

<script type="text/javascript">
   var elem = document.getElementById("mytext");
   elem.value = "My default value";
</script>
```

See: [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-a-input-field-with-javascript)

Maybe you are getting an exception from the `parseInt` that prevents the value from changing.

Answer (score -1):

If it is an option to use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/), try this:

```
function sumar(){
    $("#numero").attr("value", parseInt($("#numero").attr("value"), 10)+10);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this this will help you

```
var count=10;
$('#btnSumar').click(function(){
              if($('#numero').val()=='')
              {
                  $('#numero').val(count);
              }else

           $('#numero').val(eval($('#numero').val())+count);    

                     });
$('#btnInc').click(function(){
    $('#numero').val('');});
```

Fiddle [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/7mXmg/)

Comment: Any reason to use `eval` here?

Comment: evali used to retrive numaric value from textbox rather than string

Comment: That's what `parseFloat()`/`parseInt()` for. Other problems I see here: unsolicited use of jQuery and not cached selectors.