# Is there a way to get a big chunk of code in document.write()?

Tags: javascript, html, function, document.write

For instance, I'd like to get something like this:  in document.write

```
<form>
            <table>

            <tr>
              <td align="right">Subtotal:</td>
              <td align="left"><form name = "e" id ="e"><input type="text" id="subtotal" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="right">Sales Tax:</td>
              <td align="left"><form name = "f" id = "f"><input type="text" id="tax" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="right">Total:</td>
              <td align="left"><form name = "g" id = "g"><input type="text" id="total" /></td>
            </tr>

          </table>
    </form>
```

I tried something like

```
document.write("paste whole code here");
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Why are you wanting to do that?

Comment: document.write can't be used **after** page load, otherwise it overwrites the whole page. when are you calling `document.write()` ?

Comment: You can pass any string you want to `document.write`. It can be as long as you want. It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: I want to do it to get the values from my script to go into the text field.  That's how I got it to work on my last program, is there a way?

Comment: Does this mean you are trying to set the value of an input field? Then this would be more appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7609130/218196

Comment: @ Felix, so could that big chunk of code be a string?  Is there a way to pass that as a string and keep the formatting the same?

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't advice to do so because it makes debugging your code more difficult.

Comment: Yes Felix, I'm trying to get these values to go in the text fields I specified in the bottom of the program.  Currently, when I pressed the add item button in my program, it doesn't do anything.  I looked at my old code and it seems like I had everything in document.write, but the formatting looked awful.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Use proper DOM manipulation methods as demonstrated in the question I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record I don't encourage the use of document.write. But to answer your question, you simply need to escape the newlines in your string:

```js
    document.write('<form> \
                <table> \
                <tr> \
                  <td align="right">Subtotal:</td> \
                  <td align="left"><form name = "e" id ="e"><input type="text" id="subtotal" /></td> \
                </tr> \
                <tr> \
                  <td align="right">Sales Tax:</td> \
                  <td align="left"><form name = "f" id = "f"><input type="text" id="tax" /></td> \
                </tr> \
                <tr> \
                  <td align="right">Total:</td> \
                  <td align="left"><form name = "g" id = "g"><input type="text" id="total" /></td> \
                </tr> \
              </table> \
        </form>');
```

Comment: Thank you.  Would it be against the rules to link my other question in this comment so you, or others could see what I'm trying to do with my program?

Comment: FYI, I'm checking out the link you sent above, and trying to do it that way first.