# How does <input> tag work in this example?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Beginner javascript question. I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html) on creating forms with restricted characters.

The code is as follows:

**1. Function that limits text:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>
```

**2.Creation of Text area**

```
<form name="myform">
<textarea name="limitedtextarea" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);">
</textarea><br>
<font size="1">(Maximum characters: 100)<br>
You have <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="100"> characters left.</font>
</form>
```

I understand how the code works apart from this line:

```
You have <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="15"> characters left.</font>
```

How/why does this display the remaining characters within the text area?

Sorry for a very simple question, I am only starting in JS/HTML and this has really confused me.

Comment: Look at `limitCount.value`...

Comment: Yes I understand how it works it out, but how is it actually displayed?

Comment: It does things behind the scenes when you assign a value to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-a-input-field-with-javascript.

Comment: So <input> is always displayed on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HOW

Every time you key up, or key down within the textarea, a function is executed. That function takes 3 parameters

1. `limitField` is a reference to the actual field being typed in
2. `limitCount` is a reference to another field which is ued to display the number of remaining characters
3. `limitNum` - is a maximum number of characters you wish to allow in `limitField`

The logic of the method goes something like this (in pseudocode)

```
if the number of characters typed is greater than the mmaximum allowed characters
    truncate the field value back to the maximum allowed
otherwise
    display the number of remaining characters in the remaining count field
```

The last line there seems to be the root of your confusion, lets take that back to real code:

```
limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
```

In this line, `limitCount` is a reference to the field in the line you highlighted as your confusion in the question. `limitNum` is the maximum allowed characters, and `limitField` is the textarea being typed in to. Any input can have its text read/written using `.value`, so this line is literally saying "set the value of remaining characters field to the maximum allowed characters less the total number of characters already typed."

### WHY

Because programming.

Comment: And it's a complicated way of doing it.  :)

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. I'm confused as to the "display the no of remaining characters in the remaining count field". i.e. how does this code link specific to the <input...> area

Comment: @user9991110000 - I'll update the answer with a little more detail on that - refresh in a minute or 2