# change text for <input type=button value="select one"> from CSS

Tags: css, button

I am not able to change the text of the button from CSS

the html is -

```
<input type=button id="selBtn" value="select one">
```

I need to change the text - "select one" to "select two" from css. some thing like below what i tried -

```
input#selBtn:after 
{    
    content: 'select two'!IMPORTANT;
}
```

I also tried to make visibility hidden and then setting the values that i need and making it visible again. didnt help.

Comment: why trying from css you can simply change from html `value="select two"`

Comment: Quite simply...CSS can't do this. You need Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change your `value` in `input` with pure css.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the value of an input with CSS. The CSS content attribute has another use, read [this page](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/).

To change the value of an input with Javascript, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7609144/2976720).

Comment: i am trying to change the value of a button that is rendered by a 3rd party website in my site's iframe. They have given an option to pass the css to configure the UI on their site.

Comment: OK, but if they have some special support you should be able to find it in their documentation. In the mean time, you can very easily change the value of the button with Javascript, just take a look at the [second link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7609144/2976720) in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't change the text of an element using `content`, especially for an `<input>` or `<select>` elements which can have no descendant elements, it *is* possible if you use a `<button>` element &nadash; which *can* contain descendants:

```css
#selBtn {
  position: relative;
}
#selBtn::after {
  content: 'select two';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<button type=button id="selBtn">select one</button>
```

Note that the CSS `content` property should *not* be used to change the content presented to the user, CSS is – or should be – purely presentational; so while this is possible it's not recommended. If you really need to change the text of a form-element I'd strongly suggest using JavaScript or changing the web-page itself (either the `.html` file, or whichever server-side script generates that page).

Comment: Define what you mean by "*not working*" - where does it "not work"? In the demo here, or in your own code? If it's in your own code did you add the CSS correctly and did you change the `<input />` element into a `<button>` element?