# change input values randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**Here is my fiddle:**](http://jsfiddle.net/spdz9t3g/1/)

I have 3 text inputs, and also have one hidden input with some numbers as its value: `<input type="hidden" name="" value="100,101,105,106,109,2">.` Now I'd like to do this - when you click on 'Go' button it will randomly show one of those numbers as input values so all inputs will have value after clicking Go button. How can I do this ?

Comment: **1** array of numbers **2** setInterval **3.** Random number generation in bounds of array.length **4.** Update value of textbox.

Comment: Follow Tushar's steps, produce code and show it to us if you're in a trouble.

Comment: [Set the value of a input field with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-a-input-field-with-javascript)

Comment: is it http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/pm9vunuu/

Comment: Where is the code attempt to solve this?

Comment: @Sherali Turdiyev it is a bit like to what I want. Just now with your code same value can appear twice in 2 or 3 input fields, can we fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use following code: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/dcLojc3v/)**

```
$("#goBtn").click(function () {
    var arr = $("#values").val().split(",");
    var random = arr.splice(parseInt(Math.random()*arr.length), 1)[0];
    $("#num1").val(random);

     random = arr.splice(parseInt(Math.random()*arr.length), 1)[0];
    $("#num2").val(random);

     random = arr.splice(parseInt(Math.random()*arr.length), 1)[0];
    $("#num3").val(random);

    return false;
});
```