# JavaScript change function on a select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change what is written in the input tag depending on what was chosen in the select tag.

this is my select tag

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
    <label for="donationType">Donation Type: &nbsp;</label> 
        <select id="donationType" style="text-transform: capitalize"
                name="volunteerProject.donationTypeId" class="form-control">
            <option value='0'>Select Donation Type</option>
                <s:iterator value="donationTypeList">
                    <option value='<s:property value="donationTypeId" />'
                        name='<s:property value="donationType" />'>
                <s:property value="donationType" />
            </option>
            </s:iterator>
        </select>
</div>
```

and this is my input tag

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-3" id="vpDonateButtonLabelDiv">
    <label for="vpTitle">Button Label</label> <input
            type="text" class="form-control" id="vpDonateButtonLabel"
            name="volunteerProject.donateButtonLabel"
            placeholder="Enter button label" maxlength="50" required />
</div>
```

and here's my javascript code

```
$('#donationType').change( function() {

var donationType = $(this).val();

    if (donationType != 0) {
        if (donationType == 1){
            $("#vpDonateButtonLabelDiv").append('Donate');
        } else if (donationType == 2) {
            $("#vpDonateButtonLabelDiv").append('Volunteer');
        } else if (donationType == 3) {
            $("#vpDonateButtonLabelDiv").append('Share');
        } else if (donationType == 5) {
            $("#vpDonateButtonLabelDiv").append('Tweet');
        }
    } else {
        $("#vpDonateButtonLabelDiv").append('');
    }
});
```

However, it is not working. What did I miss here? or is my method wrong? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `id` that are you using and you have to change the `append` to `val` to change the value of the text..

```
$('#donationType').change( function() {

var donationType = $(this).val();

    if (donationType != 0) {
        if (donationType == 1){
            $("#vpDonateButtonLabel").val('Donate');
        } else if (donationType == 2) {
            $("#vpDonateButtonLabel").val('Volunteer');
        } else if (donationType == 3) {
            $("#vpDonateButtonLabel").val('Share');
        } else if (donationType == 5) {
            $("#vpDonateButtonLabel").val('Tweet');
        }
    } else {
        $("#vpDonateButtonLabel").val('');
    }
});
```

for live demo [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/bw0wkgea/)

Comment: this is exactly what I need but it doesn't work even though I've followed what you have mentioned. I'll double check my back end process, thanks!

Comment: I also provided the demo link in my answer check it. If you have any doubts than comment here.

Comment: finally! everything is working now, the problem is that my browser didn't recognize the recent changes I've made. It was solved after i empty cache and hard reload the browser. thanks so much @kalpesh!

Answer (score 1):

I see that you use jQuery already. You can replace `$("#vpDonateButtonLabelDiv").append` with `$("#vpDonateButtonLabel").val` in order to select the input and edit the value. See this fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/8odoros/mzL24b5x/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing '.append' to '.value'?
Reference: [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-a-input-field-with-javascript)

It's in javascript, but you get the idea.

Edit: Wrong selector, too. You should be changing the textbox, but your selector is your div.

try changing `$("#vpDonateButtonLabelDiv").append('Donate');` to `$("#vpDonateButtonLabel").val('Donate')`.

Comment: you're right, I should change the input area. It still doesn't work though. I've also checked that link a while ago, thanks

Comment: Does it put out any errors? Try:
`$(input[name="volunteerProject.donateButtonLabel"])` as your textbox selector

Answer (score 0):

To change the input's text, you could do something like:

```
$('#donationType').change( function() {
        var labels = ['', 'Donate', 'Volunteer', 'Share', 'Tweet' ]; //these could perhaps also be obtained from meta data?
        $('#vpDonateButtonLabel').val(labels[$(this).val()]);
});
```

But I've got an inkling you want to change the label text? If so, this can be done by finding the generated label element within the div: `$('#vpDonateButtonLabelDiv').children('label')` and setting its text.

```
$('#donationType').change( function() {
        var labels = ['', 'Donate', 'Volunteer', 'Share', 'Tweet' ]; //these could perhaps also be obtained from meta data?
        $('#vpDonateButtonLabelDiv').children('label').text(labels[$(this).val()]);
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I want to change the what is written in the `input` tag. is that even possible?

Comment: Do you mean the text inside the textbox?

Comment: yes! it changes everytime whenever I choose another option from the `select` tag

Comment: In that case you can use the first option above. Another option is a `placeholder` (watermark), as in `$('#vpDonateButtonLabel').attr("placeholder", labels[$(this).val()]);` Example: https://jsfiddle.net/03pgfn5t/