# How to send a form value from a javascript variable and be received as an integer in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

My form is going to post data to a php called numberActionPage.php. There are two buttons (a `+`, and a `-`) around the variable I am trying to post, and they simply change the variable by adding or subtracting one.  The problem I'm having is I can't find a way to retrieve the value of my Javascript `number` variable.  Another potential problem I have noticed is that `$_POST` results in a `string` in PHP.  I am not, however, concerned with negative numbers being posted to the action page, as in the actual program the number will never be lower than 1.

For instance my Javascript looks something like this:

```
var number = 5;

function subtractNumber()       {
        number--;
        document.getElementById("numberID").innerHTML = number;
}

function addNumber()    {
        number++;
        document.getElementById("numberID").innerHTML = number;
}
```

My html looks like this:

```
<form action="numberActionPage.php" method="post">
    Number:
       <button type="button" onclick="subtractNumber()">-</button>
    <a id="numberID"> <input type="hidden" value="5" name="number">  <script>document.write(number);</script>        </a>    
       <button type="button" onclick="addNumber()">+</button>
    <br>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

My numberActionPage looks like this:

```
$number = (int)htmlspecialchars($_POST['number']);
echo $number;
```

Output = `5`  on actionNumberPage

---

So, to reiterate my problem: I need a way for the `value="5"` part of my input element in my form to receive the value of the javascript variable `number`. Looking for something such as:

`value="<script>retrieveNumber()</script>"`

Also, am I preparing the `$_POST` variable correctly; turning it into an integer properly.

Thanks for your time and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want to do is updated the hidden input called number and change its value. so that when submit the value of the input will be sent to the next page like as if it was a normal input. I gave the input an id of 'inputNumber'

Like so

```
<form action="numberActionPage.php" method="post">
    Number:
       <button type="button" onclick="subtractNumber()">-</button>
    <a id="numberID"> <input type="hidden" id="inputNumber" value="5" name="number">  <script>document.write(number);</script>        </a>    
       <button type="button" onclick="addNumber()">+</button>
    <br>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Make changes to your script so that the input value is updated when the buttons are pressed.

```
function subtractNumber()       {
        number--;
        document.getElementById("numberID").innerHTML = number;
        document.getElementById("inputNumber").value = number;
}

function addNumber()    {
        number++;
        document.getElementById("numberID").innerHTML = number;
        document.getElementById("inputNumber").value = number;
}
```

Comment: @Jamin so as it turns out your question *was an exact duplicate* of [Set the value of a input field with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-a-input-field-with-javascript), right?

Comment: Yes and no, part of what I needed to do was from that answer but I had no idea how to make it work.  I think problem was more of a structural flaw that I was overlooking which was the main factor why mine wasn't working. I had seen that post before I made this one because I couldn't figure out how to place it.