# Populate div input form field value with variable data

Tags: html, forms, input, jinja2

I'm trying to display the data stored in a variable into a form field. The variable programme_title definitely holds the data as I have tested it through other methods. 
However, when I use the following, the entry form field simply reads "programme_title". How can I get the data from the variable to fill the field?

```
<div> Item 1 <input name=item_description-0-item value=programme_title> 
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the "jinja2" tag you're using [jinja2 templates](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templates/), where variables/expressions are placed in `{{ }}`:

```
<input name="item_description-0-item" value="{{ programme_title }}">
```

If it's just `HTML` + `JavaScript` then set the value property of the input element, for example by this `JavaScript` expression:

```
document.querySelector('[name="item_description-0-item"]').value = 'programme_title';
```