# How to Check URL if file exists JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need help with the following code please:

http://jsfiddle.net/geetyn6f/422/

What I need to do is to write the URL in the input

And then when I press 'Check' the answer will appear in the second input instead of the alert.

```
URL: <input type="text" name="name">
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Check</button>
Answer: <input type="text" name="answer">


$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.example.com/3.zip',
    error: function()
    {
       alert('file does not exists');
    },
    success: function()
    {
        alert('file exists');
    }
});

// Now to check if file exists call function
checkIfRemoteFileExists('http://www.yoursite.com/abc.html');

checkIfRemoteFileExists('http://www.google.de');
```

Comment: But but... you are not trying anything...

Comment: I think you need to allow cross-origin on the other side. With PHP or NodeJs can be easy.

Comment: the code working i just dont know how to change from alert to answer input

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field

Comment: @kim Yes, instead of: "  alert('file exists');  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some missing pieces in your code. But, the overall idea is to get the text of the `URL` box every time you want to make the request. After making the request, update the answer box. This is only a way to get those values. `JQuery` has a simpler way to do it. I'll leave that research to you. Click on `Run Code Snippet` and try it.

```js
function checkIfRemoteFileExists(){

  var answerBox = document.getElementById('answer'); //get the box

  $.ajax({
    url: document.getElementById('name').value, //get the value from the url box
    error: function()
    {
       answerBox.value = "file does not exists"; //update answer box
    },
    success: function()
    {
       answerBox.value = "file exists"; //update answer box
    }
  });
}

//attach function to button
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", checkIfRemoteFileExists);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
URL: <input type="text" id="name">
<button type="submit" id="button" value="Submit">Check</button>
Answer: <input type="text" id="answer">
```