# how to change input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to change input value on website using chrome development tools.

I tried many different way, but still not working.
cuz many triggers embedded there.

source page below.
https://upbit.com/exchange?code=CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-BTC

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field)

Comment: unfortunately, it doesnt work... any other way exist?