# how to set value in input by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have input field with id txt1 but I am unable to change the value from JavaScript.

```
<form action=""> 
First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementById('txt1').value('anyvalue1111');
</script>
```

**Note**: I find on stackoverflow how to change input value but could not found any answer. Title of the question save lot of time. It is valid question in this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field)

Comment: Look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7609144/5192642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is for jQuery:

```
$('#txt1').val('anyvalue1111');
```

For Javascript use:

```
document.getElementById('txt1').value = 'anyvalue1111';
```

Answer (score 5):

`value` is a property and not a method.

```
document.getElementById('txt1').value = 'anyvalue1111';
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<form action=""> 
    First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
    </form>

    <script>
    document.getElementById('txt1').value = 'Hello world!!';

    </script>
```