# Copy results displayed on HTML page not the values from a select result

Tags: html

I am using a select function with  a 2 level filter, and i can copy the result and  have it display in another box using a script, however i dont want the value in the option value field i want the actual text displayed which in my case has to be different

```
<select name="selectbranch" id="selectbranch">
    <option selected="selected" value="">-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">Basildon</option>
</select>

<select name="branch" id="branch">
    <option selected="selected" value="">-Select-</option>
    <option value="Basildon">staff1</option>
</select>

<input type="text"  id="branchstaff" name="branchstaff" placeholder="branchstaff" />

<script>
function sync() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("branch");
    var text = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
}
</script>
```

however the result is Basildon but i want the result to be staff1

Comment: I cant seem to get it working, can you help edit what i have to make it work?

Comment: "_I cant seem to get it working_" Show the code you wrote using the answer from the duplicate question and maybe we can see what is wrong.

Comment: when i change branchstaff.value = branch.value; to branchstaff.value = branch.text; i get undefined

Comment: Where is the element with the id `branchstaff`? It does not exist in your example here.

Comment: its just below as an input

Comment: <input type="text"  id="branchstaff" name="branchstaff"  placeholder="branchstaff" />

Comment: You should update your question to provide a full example which does what you are explaining. Also, your "update" is not accurate with what is described in the answer of the linked duplicate question - that answer gets the list of options, finds the selected one, etc... you just changed `.value` to `.text` which will not work.

Comment: I simply want the Text from this <option value="Basildon">staff1</option> - which is staff1, not the value- as i am using the value for something else - now i know the script has something to do with copying the contents of the text field and not the value,  with something like  var branch = document.getElementById('branch');
  var branchstaff = document.getElementById('branchstaff');
  branchstaff.value = branch.value; but this only pulls the value - Basildon and not the text, staff1 , if i can change it to pull text, im sorted

Comment: The answer to how to do that is in the question I linked you to - you just haven't done that in your code yet.

Comment: Yes but i dont know how to pull the text instead of the value

Comment: That is **exactly** what the answer to the other question explains - I don't know how to make that clearer. Read that answer, implement that in your code, done. I am not going to write it for you.

Comment: The answer doesnt work, ive tried several pages and its not working. i dont get why you cant just help me and explain why so i can learn and pass on the knowledge in the future?

Comment: its like saying, look at that person driving, do that - when i dont know how to drive...

Comment: "_The answer doesnt work_" Yes, it does. Show the code you wrote (in your question, not a comment) where you get the select element, get the selected option, then get the text as described in that answer. As I already explained, it seems all you did was just change `.value` to `.text` which is not what is described in that answer.

Comment: all of that is in my intial question, if you wont answer  and tell me " the answer is there look"  its not going to help is it?  if i dont get it , then i wont get it unless you explain.

Comment: "_all of that is in my intial question_" I don't see in your initial question where you get the selected option of the select element like in the other answer here `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex]`. All I see is you getting the select element.

Comment: I DO NOT KNOW HOW, if i did i would never have posted on here??!?!  how does that make no sense to you

Comment: `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex]` <- this _is_ how

Comment: Ive edited it to the best of my knowledge but i cant see how i would get the result into my textfield below?

Comment: [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field) - `document.getElementById("branchstaff").value = text;`

Comment: ive made the suggested changes, but the value of an input field? how do i tell the script to put the selectedindex text into a textarea? that link you provided just explains how to set the value of a select field

Comment: where would u put that?     document.getElementById("branchstaff").value = text;  in the script?

Comment: You don't have a textarea, you have an `<input type="text" />`. The link describes how to set the value of such an input field. Put that line right after you make the `text` variable in the script.

Comment: Its working now!

Comment: thank you for your help and patience, i know the old saying teach a man to fish etc, but if he doesnt even have a fishing rod he isnt getting far :)

Comment: It's like pulling teeth but you will remember this much better than if I just wrote it for you and you copy/pasted - I promise.