# How do I input the value in input field using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I m trying to add some text to the input search field using javascript

I tried below code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('contacts_modal_search_field')[0].innerHTML = \"test\
```

and many others, but unsuccessful.

this is the code :

```
<div class="contacts_modal_search">
  <input class="form-control contacts_modal_search_field no_outline ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" my-focused="" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.query" autocomplete="off" style="">
  <a class="im_dialogs_search_clear tg_search_clear ng-hide" ng-click="search.query = ''" ng-show="search.query.length" style="">
    <i class="icon icon-search-clear"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('contacts_modal_search_field')[0].value='Something'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('contacts_modal_search_field')[0].value = "test";
```

```html
 <div class="contacts_modal_search">
  <input class="form-control contacts_modal_search_field no_outline ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" my-focused="" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.query" autocomplete="off" style="">
  <a class="im_dialogs_search_clear tg_search_clear ng-hide" ng-click="search.query = ''" ng-show="search.query.length" style="">
    <i class="icon icon-search-clear"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementById("id").value = "yourvalue"` or `document.getElementsByClassName("yourclass")[index].value = "yourvalue"`.

Using `id`:

```html
Enter text to be the value of the second input field:<br/>
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" onClick="changeValue()" value="Change Value"/>
<p/>
<input type="text" id="result"/>
<script>
function changeValue(){
 document.getElementById("result").value = document.getElementById("text").value;
}
</script>
```

Using `class`:

```html
Enter text to be the value of the second input field:<br/>
    <input type="text" class="text"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" onClick="changeValue()" value="Change Value"/>
    <p/>
    <input type="text" class="result"/>
    <script>
    function changeValue(){
     document.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].value = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].value;
    }
    </script>
```

For your code:

```html
Enter text to be the value of the search input field:<br/>
    <input type="text" class="text"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" onClick="changeValue()" value="Change Value"/>
    <p/>
    <script>
    function changeValue(){
     document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].value = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].value;
    }
    </script>
<hr>
<div class="contacts_modal_search">
  <input class="form-control contacts_modal_search_field no_outline ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" my-focused="" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.query" autocomplete="off" style="">
  <a class="im_dialogs_search_clear tg_search_clear ng-hide" ng-click="search.query = ''" ng-show="search.query.length" style="">
    <i class="icon icon-search-clear"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Change value of input box on window load (using `window.onload`):

```html
        <script>
        window.onload = function(){
         document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].value = "your value";
        }
        </script>
    <div class="contacts_modal_search">
      <input class="form-control contacts_modal_search_field no_outline ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" my-focused="" type="search" placeholder="" ng-model="search.query" autocomplete="off" style="">
      <a class="im_dialogs_search_clear tg_search_clear ng-hide" ng-click="search.query = ''" ng-show="search.query.length" style="">
        <i class="icon icon-search-clear"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: there is no id in the source code, that's why I tried to use class instead

Comment: @ibobo Check my third code snippet. I incorporated your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can input in a text box using java script.

```
  <div class="contacts_modal_search">
   <input class="form-control contacts_modal_search_field no_outline ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" my-focused="" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.query" autocomplete="off" style="" id='contacts_modal_search_field'>
  <a class="im_dialogs_search_clear tg_search_clear ng-hide" ng-click="search.query = ''" ng-show="search.query.length" style="">
    <i class="icon icon-search-clear"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
//by Class name
document.getElementsByClassName('contacts_modal_search_field')[0].value='Something'

//by Id 
document.getElementById('contacts_modal_search_field')[0].value='Something' //if 'contacts_modal_search_field' is your input box ID

//By Tag name
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value='Something'
}
</script>
```

Comment: there is a api call, that should work when I use my keyboard, but if I input the text with javascript it won't, may I simulate the api call with javascript ?  – "Api call" – "contacts.search"

Comment: tell me the exact problem what you are facing

Comment: well I insert a contact name on the search box using "document.getElementsByClassName('contacts_modal_search_field')[0].value='Something'" then the contact name is in the box but the perform call didn't happened. If I use my keyboard to write any letter then the perform is made. there is no button at all "find" , when I check on console I see that on every key stroke there is contact search api call that simulate the button "find" I hope I was clear :)

Comment: it's like on every letter I write in the search box someone run the search, but when I input it using javascript no body perform the search and I have to write something and only then the search is made.

Comment: you need to call that API after inserting value in input box

Comment: call same function which you are call onchange event of textbox. just call that after document.getElementsByClassName('contacts_modal_search_field')[0].value='Something'

Comment: sorry Negi Rox, I didn't get how I can do that, is there a code that I can run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174951/discussion-between-ibobo-and-negi-rox).