# javascript onclick function is not working

Tags: javascript, onclick, addition

i tried this code in vs 2017 but it is not working. i cant console the total and other text variables but i am unable to populate the results in the text box.

```js
function myFunction1() {

  var text1 = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  console.log(text1)
  var text2 = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
  var text3 = document.getElementById("txt3").value;
  var text4 = document.getElementById("txt4").value;
  var total1 = parseFloat(text1) + parseFloat(text2) + parseFloat(text3) + parseFloat(text4);
  console.log(total1)

  document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML = total1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" />
<input type="text" id="txt4" />
<input type="text" id="total" />

<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction1()" />
```

Comment: What is happening when you are clicking it?Open browser console and see the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field)

Comment: submit buttons submit, innerHTML is not for inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `value`  instead of `innerHTML` on your result input. Because input elements doesn't have `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("monthlyAmount").value = total1
```

`innerHTML` means HTML between starting and ending tag of element.As `<input>` elements doesn't have closing tag so it has no `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `value` to set the text in your input:

```
document.getElementById("monthlyAmount").value = total1;
```