# Can't set the value of a file input with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a value on an input when button is pressed, the problem is that it's throwing an error:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Here's my code which looks pretty simple and all that:

```
document.getElementById("icon-removal-btn").onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        let label = document.getElementById("icon-label");
        let input = document.getElementById("icon-input");        
        label.innerHTML = 'Choose File';
        input.value = 'deleted';
    }
```

I even tried typing into the console `document.getElementById("icon-input").value = "deleted"` but it still didn't work. What is going on? Am I doing something wrong here?

```js
document.getElementById("icon-removal-btn").onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        let label = document.getElementById("icon-label");
        let input = document.getElementById("icon-input");        
        label.innerHTML = 'Choose File';
        input.value = 'deleted';
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col">
        <div class="form-control-lg input-group mt-1">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Upload Icon</span>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-file">
            <button class="icon-removal-button" id="icon-removal-btn">Delete</button>
            <input type="file" name="icon" id="icon-input" value="{{$card->icon}}" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
            <label class="custom-file-label" id="icon-label" for="inputGroupFile01">{{$card->icon}}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @D.Pardal snippet added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying the set the `value` of the `<input type="file">` to a string. This can't be done since `type="file"` only accepts file's as valid input.

Please read more about `type="file"` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

Removing the types fixes it (temporary)

```js
document.getElementById("icon-removal-btn").onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        let label = document.getElementById("icon-label");
        let input = document.getElementById("icon-input");        
        label.innerHTML = 'Choose File';
        input.value = 'deleted';
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col">
        <div class="form-control-lg input-group mt-1">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Upload Icon</span>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-file">
            <button class="icon-removal-button" id="icon-removal-btn">Delete</button>
            <input name="icon" id="icon-input" value="{{$card->icon}}" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
            <label class="custom-file-label" id="icon-label" for="inputGroupFile01">{{$card->icon}}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: setting input.value = 'deleted'; to input.value = ''; will fix the error while preserving functionality

Answer (score 4):

From the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#common-input-element-apis) (emphasis mine):

> ***input* . `value` [ = *value* ]**
>
> Returns the current value of the form control.
>
> Can be set, to change the value.
>
> *Throws an "`InvalidStateError`" `DOMException` if it is set to any value other than the empty string when the control is a file upload control.*

So you can't change the `value` of a `<input type="file">` to anything other than `""`.

Answer (score 3):

`input.value` can only be assigned a text content on text objects (see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp).

An `<input type="text">`, for example, can have a `value` assigned to it:

```js
document.getElementById('test').value = 'Success.';
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test">
```

An `<input type="file">`, however, cannot have a text `value` assigned to it, because it does not have text content.

The snippet below will not work and throws a script error:

```js
document.getElementById('test').value = 'Success.';
```

```html
<input type="file" id="test">
```

This would cause the same error as you experienced:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

---

**Update**

An `<input type="file">` does *have* a value, but can't be set to anything other than `""`. See the answer by D. Pardal for more info.

Comment: It has a value, you just can't change it to anything other than `""`.

Comment: Thanks for that info! I hope your ok with the way I've edited my answer, and don't see it as copying yours?