# Value of input is text not changing

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following code

```js
//main.js
var textinput = document.getElementById('textinput').value;

function textChanger() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    textinput = 'newtext';
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> some title </title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" value="sometext" id="textinput" oninput="textChanger()">
  <script type="text/javascript" scr="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect that the value of textinput should be changed after 3 seconds but it isn't changing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you are *copying* the text from the `<input>` to the variable. Unlike objects, primitives (like strings) are passed by value. That means that when you update the variable, you are not updating the `<input>` value.

This code works:

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById('textinput');

function textChanger() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    inputElement.value = 'newtext';
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- Don't forget the doctype! -->
<html>

<head>
  <title> some title </title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" value="sometext" id="textinput" oninput="textChanger()">
  <script type="text/javascript" scr="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `value` property of the input.

```js
var textinput = document.getElementById('textinput');

function textChanger() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      textinput.value = 'newtext';
   }, 3000);
}


textChanger();
```

```html
<input type="text" value="sometext" id="textinput" oninput="textChanger()">
```

You can find lot of details here:

[Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field)

Comment: Value is there. But it is just a JS string. It has no backward binding to the DOM element.