# Get div attribute value in input value and change in source

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onclick

I need show my newprice="" in input value, and in source.

```js
$(".uzmi").on("click", function(e) {
  $("inid").val($(this).attr('newprice'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-value="VALUE 1" class="uzmi product-variation-colors__item helmet-variations" id=" " codeproduct=" " newprice="6043" variation_id="1407" change_img(0) "> Div 1</div>
<div data-value="VALUE 1 " class="uzmi product-variation-colors__item helmet-variations " id=" " codeproduct=" " newprice="2323 " variation_id="1407 " change_img(0)"> Div 2</div>
<div data-value="VALUE 1" class="uzmi product-variation-colors__item helmet-variations" id=" " codeproduct=" " newprice="9999" variation_id="1407" change_img(0) "> Div 3</div>
<input type=" " id="inid " name="variation_id " class="variation_id " value="6041 " />
```

This working for me, but I want my value to change in the source as well, not only visually.

Comment: You can't change the source code once it's been parsed. "This is working for me" -- no, it's not; you have a typo in your code.

Comment: Note: I created a snippet of your code BUT your HTML as presented is invalid (as in your JavaScript/jQuery code)  SO I voted to close because of these typo's

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`inid.setAttribute("value", price)` added this line to update DOM too

Solution with Vanilla JavaScript

```js
const inid = document.getElementById('inid')

const getPrice =(e)=> {
  let price = e.getAttribute('newprice')
  e.setAttribute('source', 'clicked')
  
  inid.value=price;
  inid.setAttribute("value", price)
}
```

```css
[source="clicked"] { color: green }
```

```html
<p>Click on DIV</p>

<div onclick="getPrice(this)" data-value="VALUE 1" class="uzmi product-variation-colors__item helmet-variations" id=" " codeproduct=" " newprice="6043" variation_id="1407" change_img(0)"> Div 1</div>

<div onclick="getPrice(this)" data-value="VALUE 1" class="uzmi product-variation-colors__item helmet-variations" id=" " codeproduct=" " newprice="2323" variation_id="1407" change_img(0)"> Div 2</div>


<div onclick="getPrice(this)" data-value="VALUE 1" class="uzmi product-variation-colors__item helmet-variations" id=" " codeproduct=" " newprice="9999" variation_id="1407" change_img(0)"> Div 3</div>


<input type="" id="inid" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="6041" />
```

Comment: Yes, but no change in source, when I go to inspect. I need in inspect too. Thanks.

Comment: An answer should have an explanation, not just code and "try this" or words to that affect.

Comment: inid.setAttribute("value", price) added this line to update DOM too

Comment: [Be aware of the gotchas when using `setAttribute("value", value)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24288432/215552)

Comment: Thanks. This working, but i have already ONCLICK atributte. 

onclick="change_img(<?php echo  $index; ?>)">

and your. 

Can I split in one onclick function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "#" within you click function like this, because you are selecting by id:

```
$(".uzmi").on("click", function(e) {
       $("#inid").val($(this).attr('newprice'));
 });
```

And to the second part of your question, what do you mean by "source"?

Comment: Yes, but not change in source. Just visual in input.

Comment: Yes, butt no change in source, when I go to inspect. I need in inspect too. Thanks.

Comment: @marko what exactly do you mean as source? Do you mean data-value of an input?

Comment: When I click change working, when I click the changes work, but I want them to change automatically in Inspect. Click on inupt value right click and go to Inspect.

I hope you understand

Comment: @marko When you click Inspect, in the right pane, select Properties. If you look at the `value` property, you'll find it has changed. Thus, "Inspect" has changed, as desired.