How to populate my form fields when one of my errors are triggered using JavaScript?
I am currently making a website and have implemented in a login system, with this I have introduced some form validation, however whenever an error occurs the data in my form disappears. I have managed to store it to local data, however I'm wondering how to populate the form fields.
Here is my signup.php file:
<?php
    include_once 'header.php';
?>

<section class="signup-form">
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <div class="signup-form-form">
       <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full name...">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email...">
        <input type="text" name="uid" id="uid" placeholder="Username...">
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Pasword...">
        <input type="password" name="pwdrepeat" placeholder="Repeat password...">
        <button type="submit" name = "submit" onclick="storeFormData()">Sign Up</button>
     </form>
     <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login</a></p>
    </div>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET["error"])){
        if ($_GET["error"] == "emptyinput") {
            echo "<p>Fill in all fields!<p>";
        }
        else if ($_GET["error"] == "invaliduid") {
            echo "<p>Choose a proper username!<p>";
        }
        else if ($_GET["error"] == "invalidemail") {
            echo "<p>Choose a proper email!<p>";
        }
        else if ($_GET["error"] == "passwordnotmatch") {
            echo "<p>Passords don't match!<p>";

        }
        else if ($_GET["error"] == "stmtfailed") {
            echo "<p>Something went wrong, try again!<p>";

        }
        else if ($_GET["error"] == "usernametaken") {
            echo "<p>Username already taken!<p>";

        }
        else if ($_GET["error"] == "none") {
            echo "<p>You have signed up!<p>";

        }
    }
    ?>
</section>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>


And here is my script.js file:

    // Function to store form data in local storage
    function storeFormData() {
        const formData = {
            name: document.getElementById('name').value,
            email: document.getElementById('email').value,
            uid: document.getElementById('uid').value
        };

        const jsonData = JSON.stringify(formData);
        localStorage.setItem('formData', jsonData);
    }
    
}



I have tried using setItem however it doesn't seem to work, i'd like to add that I only want to populate the fields if one of my errors are triggered.

Have you tried to search first? Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-default-value-of-an-input-field

For the JS part, here is how I usually do the getter and setter for the data, should look something like this:
function getFormData() {
    const form = document.getElementById('myForm');
    const formDataObj = {};

    // Loop through form elements and populate formDataObj
    for (const input of form.elements) {
        formDataObj[input.name] = input.value;
    }

    console.log(formDataObj); // Output the form data object (for testing)
    return formDataObj;
}

and
function setFormData() {
     const formDataObj = {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        email: "johndoe@example.com"
    };

    const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

    // Loop through the object keys and set form values
    for (const key in formDataObj) {
        if (formDataObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const inputElement = form.elements[key];
            if (inputElement) {
                inputElement.value = formDataObj[key];
            }
        }
    }
}

