# Clicking the row of the table and displaying it to text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have text field inside the table, and also the data below in it..I want to display the data to text field after clicking the row.

I tried these code but nothing happens. Help me please.

These are the code for the table.

```html
<table id="tableqwe">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Id Number</th>
<th>Course</th>
<th>Year level</th>
<th>School Year</th>
<th>Semester</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
   
<tr>
<th><input type="Text" id="name1" name="name1" style="width:200px;"></th>
<th><input type="Text" id="idnumber2" name="idnumber2" style="width:200px;"></th>
<th><input type="Text" id="course3" name="course3" style="width:80px;"></th>
<th><input type="Text" id="yearlvl4" name="yearlvl4" style="width:200px;"></th>
<th><input type="Text" id="schoolyear5" name="schoolyear5" style="width:150px;"></th>
<th><input type="Text" id="semester6" name="semester6" style="width:100px;"></th>
<th><input type="button" value="Add" class="btntable edit" style="width:50px;"></th>
</tr>
    
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Id_number'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['course'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['year_level'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['school_year'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['semester'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>"?><input type="button" class="btntable delete" value="Delete" style="width:50px;"><?php
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

And these are the javascript code...

```js
<script>
    var table1 = document.getElementById('tableqwe');
    
    for(var i = 2; i < table1.rows.length; i++)
    {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function()
        {
            rIndex = this.rowIndex;
            console.log(rIndex);
            
             document.getElementsByName("name1").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
             document.getElementsByName("idnumber2").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
             document.getElementsByName("course3").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
             document.getElementsByName("yearlvl4").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
             document.getElementsByName("schoolyear5").value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
             document.getElementsByName("semester6").value = this.cells[5].innerHTML;  
        }
    }
</script>
```

Can someone help me with this.! All I want is if I click any row of the table, it will directly display it to the text field.

Comment: Hi thanks for your respond..I tried your code but still nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr contenteditable = 'true' id='name' data-name= '//php variable like $id '>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>"?><input type="button"  class="btntable delete" value="Delete" style="width:50px;"><?php
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

then change your javascript to like this (Im coding it Jquery and change it you want.)

```
<Script>
  $(document).on('click', '#button Id or Class here', function(){  

    //get id of user updates
    var id = $(this).data("name");
    // get values 
     var val = $(this).text();


      });  

</script>
```

this the solution. if is this help for your leave a comment.

Comment: Hi Namindu, I tried your code but still nothing happened..it only makes the table editable.

Comment: That is not your want? do you want get user input in your table?

Comment: Hi Namindu, what i want is when the user clicks the row, it display directly to the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HTML DOM getElementById()` Method to get the element with the specified ID.

`HTML DOM getElementsByName() Method` Get all elements with the specified name.

You have to edit your js script as follows.

- If you are using 'HTML DOM getElementsByName() Method'  to assign value to that specific element you should use it as `document.getElementsByName("name1")[0].value="value"`. Since this method returns the collection of objects having the same name passed as it's parameter.
- If you are using the `HTML DOM getElementById()` you can assign values into it by using the code as `document.getElementById("idofelement").value="value".`

An example is given in the snippet below.

```js
 
    var table1 = document.getElementById('tableqwe');
    
    for(var i = 2; i < table1.rows.length; i++)
    {
        table1.rows[i].onclick = function()
        {
            rIndex = this.rowIndex;
            console.log(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
           
             document.getElementById("name1").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
             console.log(document.getElementsByName("name1")[0].value);
             document.getElementById("idnumber2").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
             document.getElementById("course3").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
             document.getElementById("yearlvl4").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
             document.getElementById("schoolyear5").value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
             document.getElementById("semester6").value = this.cells[5].innerHTML;  
        }
    }
```

```html
<table id="tableqwe">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Id Number</th>
<th>Course</th>
<th>Year level</th>
<th>School Year</th>
<th>Semester</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
   
<tr>
<th><input type="Text" id="name1" name="name1" style="width:200px;"></th>
<th><input type="Text" id="idnumber2" name="idnumber2" style="width:200px;"></th>
<th><input type="Text" id="course3" name="course3" style="width:80px;"></th>
<th><input type="Text" id="yearlvl4" name="yearlvl4" style="width:200px;"></th>
<th><input type="Text" id="schoolyear5" name="schoolyear5" style="width:150px;"></th>
<th><input type="Text" id="semester6" name="semester6" style="width:100px;"></th>
<th><input type="button" value="Add" class="btntable edit" style="width:50px;"></th>
</tr>
    
<tr>
 <td>name</td>
 <td>12</td>
 <td>Course</td>
 <td>Course 12</td>
 <td>School year 12</td>
   <td>School year 12</td>
<td><input type="button" class="btntable delete" value="Delete" style="width:50px;"></tr>;
 
</table>
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output?

Comment: It's `getElementsByName` . Note the plural. It returns an array-like NodeList of elements with that name attribute. getElementbyName  doesn't exsts. `getElementsByName` exists, which returns a collection of the elements. If you plan to find only one:

`document.getElementsByName("hi")[0].setAttribute("value", "my value is high");`   see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980830/javascript-getelementbyname-doesnt-work.

Comment: So is it better to use the getElementsbyId?

Comment: Yeah. as my example demonstrated above. Note that Id should be unique. Just try getElementsbyId and give your feed back. Most probably it will work.

Comment: Where that script is included? Is it after that table?

Comment: Not exactly, Can you share your code that you have done so far for better identification of your problem.?

Comment: var table1 = document.getElementById('tableqwe');

Comment: ive change the getElementByName to getElementById

Comment: Also change getElementsByName() to getElementById inside the loop. Is it already done?