# Is it true IE 8 doesn't support .length property?

Tags: javascript

[image: Question]

I have to use a picture, Stackoverflow says:

*Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
    Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.*

**The screenshot was taken from Stackoverflow's form.**

Comment: On different note, why don't you just indent the code as instructed.

Comment: I did indent the code.. infact.. I don't use <code>, still got the same message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Internet Explorer has no problems with the length property. If it didn't support it, then it would report `undefined` not `0`.

The HTML is invalid, there is no `name` attribute for the `div` element. Internet Explorer is just error recovering in a different way to Firefox and not matching the div elements with `getElementsByName`

> Elements that support both the NAME attribute and the ID attribute are included in the collection returned by the getElementsByName method, but **elements with a NAME  expando are not included** in the collection.

— [MSDN getElementsByNameMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536438%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Use a class instead. Internet Explorer 8 doesn't have a native `getElementsByClassName`, but there are no shortage of [cross-browser implementations](http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/) or you could use a [selector engine](http://microjs.com/#css) or a big library that includes one such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Comment: I've used `class` for anything else, and also ID, is there any other way to substitute the `name`? and works in IE of course..

Comment: Eh? That does make much sense. You do know that the class attribute takes a space separated list of classes (plural!)? So if the element already has a class, that won't stop you giving it another one. Either way, `name` is just plain wrong, don't use it.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByName` is for use on `input` HTML elements - DIV elements do not have `name` attributes

Comment: I don't think you mean **Tag** Name there.

Comment: it's plural `getElementsByName`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that .length is not working on IE, but that getElementByName() is not working on IE... : [getElementsByName in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7)