# How do I get values of input element with the same name as an javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get values of the input element that those elements are under the same name, name="items[]"
for example:

```
<div>...<input type="text" name="items[]" value="1" /></div>
<div>...<input type="text" name="items[]" value="2" /></div>
<div>...<input type="text" name="items[]" value="3" /></div>
```

And I wish to get the result something like:

```
[1, 2, 3] //that store in an javascript variable.
```

Do I need to do a loop to access all the elements to get its value?
Please give me a good solution either javascript or JQuery.
Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to ACCEPT an answer?

Comment: If you click on your profile, Alwayz, you can clearly see in RED letters : 'Have you considered to accept one answer?' You think it's here by mistake?

Comment: ok, I understand, but i just post a question. I'll wait to see which answer that useful for me and i'll vote them up

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
var values = [];
$("input[name='items[]']").each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: hi Igor, i'm sorry for unclear question, all the elements are in the div elements as i corrected above.

Comment: this selector will select input elements even if they are inside the div; you may use `$("div input[name='items[]']")` if you want to be sure

Comment: but it alerts nothing. I used to try $('classname').each(function() { values += $(this).val() }); but it also show nothing

Comment: ok, thanks Igor, it works, I have a problem with my code, that y it doesn't work, thank you much ^^

Answer (score 8):

JavaScript only:

```
var values = [];
var fields = document.getElementsByName("items[]");
for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    values.push(fields[i].value);
}
```

Warning, see: [getElementsByName in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7)

Comment: i think there would be problems with `getElementsByName` in IE

Comment: @igor agreed jQuery is the way to go, but the OP asked for both

Answer (score 4):

Or use jQuery's map function:

```
$("div input[name='items[]']").map( function() { return $(this).val(); } ).get();
```

Comment: Be careful with .map(), in some browsers it returns an array but in others it returns an object `m.fn.init[]` (Chrome). This latter one cannot be stringified by JSON.stringify(). Specifically, the following two are NOT equivalent: `var arr=$('input[name="foo"]').map(function(){return this.value}).get()` with `var arr=[]; $('input[name="foo"]').each(function(){arr.push(this.value)})`. In the first case `arr` is not an Array whereas in the latter case it is. `JSON.stringify(arr)` fails for the former, but works for the latter.