# Highlight input with heights value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

i got a group of inputs... each one has a number value.
i want to get all their values (found a method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7157670/915636)) and then compare
then and highlight the heighest input meaning highlight the input itself
meaning i need to somehow grab its id and know which one i am comparing to...

(i hope i explained it good).

**This is what i have for now taken from the link attached:**

```
var values = [];
$("input[name='items[]']").each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
        $(function(){
            var higesht_val = 0;
            var higesht_val_id = 0;
            $("input[name='items[]']").each(function() {
                var current_val = parseInt(this.value);
                if(higesht_val < current_val){
                    higesht_val = current_val;
                    higesht_val_id =  this.id;
                }
            });

            alert(higesht_val); // highest value
            alert(higesht_val_id);// id of  highest value input
        })
```

Comment: What if the elements don't have IDs?

Comment: @ahren meaning i need to somehow grab its id and know : Sagive SEO.So it is sure elem have id

Comment: Yee... it has an id - what i need to higlight it (attach a class) is the id for other calculations.. Thanks - Runing a test on your answer now ;)

Comment: Cool! this works! - i only had to add a parseInt so the check would work <-- please edit your answer for other people - instead of higesht_val = this.value;  its actually higesht_val = parseInt(this.value);  Thanks a lot for your help, nice touch to integrate the alerts (time saver).

Answer (score 1):

```
var highestVal = 0,
    $target;
$("input[name='items[]']").each(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) > highestVal){
      highestVal = parseInt($(this).val());
      $target = $(this);
    }
});

// $target is now the input with the highest value
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. i actually stated that i need the ID also and @rajeshkakawat solution worked almost "out the box" but i apreaciate the time you spent.

Answer (score 0):

how about this ?

```
var values = [];
$("input[name='items[]']").each(function() {values.push(this);});
values.sort(function(a, b){return  b.value - a.value;})
highlight(values[0]);
```