# Make div height of two other divs

Tags: javascript, css

i have a div, `div1` with a height according to the text, `div2` is the same. Now i need `div3` to be: `div1` + `div2`

I have this code, but it ain't workin.

```
var lengthnews1 = ((document.getElementById("div1").offsetHeight)+"px");
var lengthnews2 = ((document.getElementById("div2").offsetHeight)+"px");
var x = document.getElementById("div3");
x.height = (lengthnews1 + lengthnews2);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158847/javascript-dom-on-ie/7158950#7158950

Comment: You might also wanna check out Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/), so you can step through and debug your javascript...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to add two strings, not numbers. Fetch both heights, add them and then add the "px" :

```
var lengthnews1 = ((document.getElementById("div1").offsetHeight));
var lengthnews2 = ((document.getElementById("div2").offsetHeight));

var x = document.getElementById("div3");
x.height = (lengthnews1 + lengthnews2) + "px";
```

You can verify the working code at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3dhz/2/)

Comment: @1ntello: Happy to help, these kind of small bugs drive me crazy as well!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "px" from lengthnews1 and lengthnews2 variables so you can add the two values together for var x, once added you can then add the "px".

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height using x.style.height
Also you need to concat with "px" only once, ie (lengthnews1 + lengthnews2) + "px"