# IE 0.width is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I'm Doing a Javascript and jQUery animation and it is working quite fine in all browsers less in Internet Explorer, it shows this alert: '0.width is null or not an object' take a look at the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/3y8cN/

It's a animated Percent bar, that works just fine in Chrome, but not in IE, looks that the problem is in the `if`:

```
if (barracent[0].style.width != '0'){
    multiplier[0].innerHTML = value1+'%';
}
```

How can I avoid that Problem?

Yes, I Know that I can use loops to avoid that big code, I'll do it later.
Thanks a lot in Advance.

Comment: Use jQuery to select elements with a class, not a name. Use each to loop through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DIV`'s do not support the 'name' attribute, and so `document.getElementsByName('barracent')` is not returning any elements in IE (other browsers must not have this restriction).  Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/278773/508537) for more details on the issue.

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot, but in that case, should I use QuerySelector to get them by class or use one ID for Each div? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto:  It's up to you.  Either way should work fine, but be consistent :)

Comment: querySelectorAll didnt work fine in IE, In trying to do it with another way. Thanks again

Comment: All Fine now, I had to use each one by ID, but it worked nice, Thanks again!

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto Hmmm...querySelectorAll worked fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/3y8cN/1/.  Anyway, glad I could help :)

Comment: Wierd... Anyway, now I know something else about that! Thanks again!