# javascript getElementsByName does not work on divs

Tags: javascript

I cannot use id

```
<javascript>
divs = document.getElementsByName("mydiv");
console.log('length: ' + divs.length);

<body>

<div name='mydiv'>foo</div>
<div name='mydiv'>bar</div>
</body>
```

console: 0

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [getElementsByName in IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7)

Answer (score 11):

There is no `name` attribute for `div` elements.

Write [valid](http://validator.w3.org/) HTML and use a class instead (with [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)).

Comment: also there is no `javascript` tag

Comment: And make sure you call the script after elements has been rendered or you still get nothing