# JavaScript code not working IE8

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make links work which we click to change the language of website using JavaScript. Here is the HTML code:

```
'<form action="" method="post" name="currlang">'.
    '<input type="hidden" name="languageval" value="'.$session->value("language").'"/>'.
    '<a onclick="langa(this, \'en\');" class="langs'.($session->value("language")=='en'?" active":"").'" id="en"></a>'.
    '<a onclick="langa(this, \'it\');" class="langs'.($session->value("language")=='it'?" active":"").'" id="it"></a>'.
    '<a onclick="langa(this, \'pl\');" class="langs'.($session->value("language")=='pl'?" active":"").'" id="pl"></a>'.
'</form>'.
```

and here the javascript:

```
function langa(obj, valu) {
    document.getElementsByName("languageval")[1].value=valu;
    document.getElementsByName('currlang')[1].submit();
}
```

The script works fine on new browsers (Firefoxe, Opera, Chrome, IE9) but when testing it on IE8 it gives an error:

> "'document.getElementsByName(...).1' is null or not an object".

After some research I found out that `getElementsByName()` is not supported by IE8 and above and maybe the solution would be to use jQuery and this is where I need help.
How can I make this work with jQuery or without it?

Comment: You only have one input named `languageval` so its index is `[0]`, not `[1]`

Comment: you can always put an ID on the inputs and use getElementById. Make sure the ID are unique

Comment: since you specified jquery in the tags, how come you're not actually using it in your code?

Comment: Take a look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using an `ID` or `class` to achieve the same purpose instead of `name`.

Example:

```
<div id="foo">This is id of foo</div>
<div class="choo">This is class of choo</div>
```

Then if you use `ID` then use:

```
document.getElementById('foo');
```

and with `class` use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('choo');
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help pathurs but it does the than mikeswright49 it just refreshes the page.

Comment: Can you post more code? It's hard to understand it when it's only a very small section

Answer (score -1):

For this to work the way you want switch name to Id.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function langa (obj, valu){
      $("#languageval").val(valu);
      $("#currlang").submit();
   }
</script>
```

The # will pull the element with that Id and val() is the get/set for the element's value.

Edit: added the type and language tags to

Comment: Probably won't work correctly because OP uses `name` instead of the `id` attribute.

Comment: He said he wanted to use JQuery, so I gave him the JQuery way, but this is why I said he needs to switch name to id in the first line.

Comment: Thank you mikeswright49. I have tried your code and the page refresh but the language doesn't switch.

Comment: This is a Jquery implementation have you included jquery?

Comment: Yes I have included jquery v1.7.2

Comment: and you've switched the elements from using name to id right?

Comment: Yes I did exactly as you said.

Comment: Alright, have you added this to your html file <script src=".../jquery-1.7.2.js")" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" ></script> with the ... being the path? otherwise I can't see why it wouldn't work, sorry.