# Javascript failing in IE

Tags: javascript

I have code written in JScript for a website I have implemented.  The script is pretty straightforward, nothing too fancy.  It works in Chrome and Firefox, but it does not execute in IE.  I am getting the error

```
SSCRIPT5007: Unable to get the value of 'style': Object is null of undefined.
```

Now, I have already checked online for possible solutions.  The one I see the most is that I need to include X-UA-Compatible in my meta tag, but it is already in there.  Is there any other solution?

Specifically, my code fails at this part:

```
var extra_options = document.getElementsByName("myExtraOptions");
for(thisindex = 0; thisindex < 7; thisindex++) {
        extra_options[thisindex].style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Comment: And your js code is ... ? We cannot guess your code.

Comment: Forgot to add that part, heh...

Comment: The element you are trying to modify the style of does not exist.

Comment: What is `extra_options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if that element exists something like:

```
for(thisindex = 0; thisindex < 7; thisindex++) {
        if(extra_options[thisindex] !== undefined) {
            extra_options[thisindex].style.display = 'none';
        }
}
```

and you can check how many elements with that name exists:

```
var extra_options = document.getElementsByName("myExtraOptions");
alert(extra_options.length);
```

Comment: Okay, did that, and you were right, extra_options doesn't exist.  Is there a difference between IE and Chrome/Firefox in declarations that will not allow me to do this?

Comment: I mean, I specifically created elements with the name "myExtraOptions", so I KNOW they exist.

Comment: No, is not difference between IE and Chrome because JS is same for these browsers. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7

Comment: What are the types of the "myExtraOptions" elements? If they are not input elements (or something) you could expect to not get them, maibe using a className will get the desired results.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting ClientIDMode="Static" in your page header.