# getElementsByName is not working on ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, getelementsbyname

This is my js function which run succesfully on chrome, safari, firefox. But on ie isn't working. How to solve it?

```
function submitThis(name){
    var form= document.getElementsByName(name)[0];
    form.submit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How IE version you tested?

Comment: I tested it now in IE. My code work:


HTML:
`<form action="someaction" name="someform">
<textarea id="t"></textarea><br>
<input type="text" id="f">
<input type="button"  value="Go">
</form>`

Javascript: `var form= document.getElementsByName('someform')[0];
   form.submit();`

It work on IE>=7

Comment: I chose the wrong duplicate, I misread `getElementsByClassName` check this question see if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7

Comment: i couldnt solve my problem you sent me. I tried document.getElementById method but doesnt work also

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else then. Are you sure the element exists by the time you run the script? I'd suggest you create a demo in http://jsfiddle.net, and get it to reproduce the error, then open a new question, post the code that failed, and tell us what version of IE fails.