# Web application triggers different button after using meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"

Tags: internet-explorer, email, meta-tags, http-equiv

I have an Classic ASP application. The application will now be used in **IE11**, and for making it compatible with the same, I used the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

The page triggers emails to people who are mentioned in them. The page has two buttons, namely **Back** and **Submit**.

**Back**:

```
<button class="buttonInput"
                  style="cursor:hand"
                  name="btnBack"
                  value="Back"
                  onClick="javascript:history.back()">Back</button>
```

**Submit**:

```
<button class='buttonInput' style='cursor:hand' name='btnSubmit' value='Submit' onClick='javascript:document.forms[0].submit()'>Submit</button>
```

The usual behavior of the page is to send emails once submit is clicked.
But once the `<meta>` is included, the Cancel button too triggers mails.

Any Ideas as to why this could be happening? I really am not able to decipher the issue.

**PS:** I have used other versions of IE in my meta tag and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: This behaviour has nothing to do with the fact it is a Classic ASP web application, issues here are browser compatibility related.

Comment: I know. I'm curious to know if there is any syntactical way to solve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see the rest of the markup, it's hard to say.  I'm reasonably certain your app is running either as an IE5 app (because there's no doctype) or in IE8 standards mode.

Either way, you're dealing a legacy rendering issue that's not present in versions.  I suspect you've some script dependency on [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533560(v=vs.85).aspx) or [name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7), as I seem to recall there were some parsing differences in earlier versions.

There's also a possibility that [IE11 enterprise mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640687) (EMIE) will help.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Hi Lance, I did notice that the page doesn't have a `doctype`  . So, will using the meta tag with IE5 help solve the problem? Also, we are not to use the `EMIE` mode, but solve the issue programmatically.

Comment: With the class shared between the buttons, I wondered if you were using getElementByID to search for an object and then triggering something on the result.  IE8 included a behavior change that seemed potentially relevant  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx).  Based on your current x-ua-compatible value, the docmode depends on the doctype.  Check the documentMode property at runtime or use a specific value (`IE=8`) to select the mode you really want (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hi! A quick update : The no `doctype` clue helped me a lot. I found that `EmulateIE7` works for me. Thanks a lot Lance.