# document.getElementsByName.length return 0 in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I know document.getElementsByName works differently in IE and Firefox, in IE, it returns HTMLCollection, while in Firefox, it returns NodeList.

In Firefox, the code is working correctly, while in IE, it always return length 0. The IE version is 11.

The code is:

```
var fullToken = document.getElementsByName("0");
console.log(fullToken.length);

  <span name ="0">h</span>
  <span name ="0">e</span>
  <span name ="0">l</span>
  <span name ="0">l</span>
  <span name ="0">o</span>
```

Comment: which version of IE

Comment: It's 11. Thanks.

Comment: I guess it must be something else causing a problem.

Comment: It's for IE7, but it's Microsoft...: [getElementsByName in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. The `span` element cannot have a `name` attribute.

Internet Explorer appears to be ignoring the `name` attribute on elements where it is forbidden. If you change a `span` to an `input` it will show up in the list.

If you want to describe a group of elements for referencing with JavaScript, use a `class` with `getElementByClassName`.

Comment: But the example documentation here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName#Example shows a div with `name` attribute... Isn't the span must be treated as a div

Comment: Why span cannot have name attribute?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki — The example MDN gives is invalid. https://validator.w3.org/nu reports "Error: Attribute name not allowed on element div at this point."

Comment: @connexo — Not in Internet Explorer, and the code in the question demonstrates.

Comment: @typeofprogrammer — In the bad old days, `name` was massively overloaded and used for all sorts of things. As HTML was standardised, those various functions were split out and shared between `name`, `id` and `class`. The primary function of `name` is to provide a key to be associated with data entered into a form control when that form is submitted. A span is not a form control.

Comment: @connexo MSDN (I don't know if this is still relevant, but it matches the behavior): _"When you use the `getElementsByName` method, all elements in the document that have the specified `NAME` attribute or `ID` attribute value are returned. Elements that support both the `NAME` attribute and the `ID` attribute are included in the collection returned by the `getElementsByName` method, **but elements with a `NAME` expando are not included in the collection**; therefore, this method cannot be used to retrieve custom tags by name"_ ([Src](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ms536438(v=vs.71)))

Comment: @Quentin you are right, it's working now if I change the name attribute to class. Thanks a lot.